# Detect BSOD on Windows

Tags: windows, exception, detect, bsod

Is there any way to detect if a BSOD has just occurred(before the OS shutdowns)?

Thanks,

Comment: And if one has, do what?

Comment: We have applications running on other CPUs(affined to other CPUs), we at least try to inform and restart them gracefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kernel provides limited functionality for drivers to be informed of a bugcheck (i.e., BSOD) via [KeRegisterBugCheckCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff553105%28VS.85%29.aspx).  In the callback routine, you can attempt a graceful shutdown of your applications, etc.  However, given that the system is bugchecking, most functionality will not be available.

Answer (score 1):

Not to my knowledge. A BSOD usually means a hardware malfunction which results in the computer not being able to work/run.

If you have experienced one BSOD it would be wise to investigate the report document as the BSOD is most likely to return.

Most frequent causes are drivers not being up to date or memory malfunction. I have also seen hard drives cause BSODs.